# Do two elements of the same CSS class on the same webpage always have identical CSS properties?

Tags: css

Do two elements of the same CSS class on the same webpage always have identical CSS properties? I am wondering because I need to gather all the CSS properties of each element on a webpage and I am wondering if I should gather CSS properties corresponding to CSS class or CSS id and if there would be a difference between those?

Comment: No, they don't always have identical CSS properties, because of the cascade and inheritance. Consider: `.white { color: white; } .gray { color: gray; } .white .gray { color: black; }` and `<div class="white"><div class="gray">What color?</div></div><div class="gray">What color?</div>`.

Comment: In addition to the points made by @HereticMonkey , I wonder what you mean by _gather CSS properties of each element_ on a page? Do you need to determine _every style rule_ applied to it? Are you documenting _all user defined styles_? Browsers have built-in default styles for HTML elements to render them unless user style sheets are provided. E.g. `<h1 class="red">`, `<p class="red">`, and `<dd class="red">` will most likely render differently even though they have the same class.

Comment: If you want to find all the css properties that apply to an element you may be better off using getComputedStyle rather than try to interpret style sheets and inline styling and inbuilt styling yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what your objective is but class in CSS applies to a host of elements whereas id applies to only one element. In terms of if all CSS properties are inherited by class that depends you can specify attributes that go inside of nested elements, child elements, float properties, hover properties etc. for example `.classHere> button{color:green; float:center;}`

Check out this link for further examples https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score -1):

If you add a class to an HTML element, you can give the class to every element you want, and it will share with all the element with that class the properties defined on the CSS document. That's is the fundamental of Bootstrap.

On the other side ID's are unique to the element, so you can use them ONLY in one HTML item. So for example you can have an h1 and h2 sharing the same class, but never the same ID.